# LaTeX \rule filling the line

Tags: latex, rule

Why does the following command not produce a horizontal rule filling the space until the end of the line?

```
Hello \rule[0.5em]{\fill}{1pt}
```

It is my understanding that this should print the text “`Hello`” followed by a horizontal rule that extends until the end of the line, analogously to the macro `\hfill` which is effectively equivalent to `\hspace\fill`. – But in effect, this command just produces the text “`Hello`”, no rule.

I am aware that the effect can be produced by `\hrulefill` but it can’t be used here because I want a *raised* rule and `\hrulefill` doesn’t work together with `\raisebox` and I want my rule to hang *above* the baseline (at best in the middle of the line).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't have a satisfying answer as to why the command you presented doesn't work, but I can offer an effective workaround.  Put

```
% Raised Rule Command:
%  Arg 1 (Optional) - How high to raise the rule
%  Arg 2            - Thickness of the rule
\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}
```

into your document's preface, and then you can accomplish what you were hoping to with:

```
Hello \raisedrule[0.5em]{1pt}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t understand how this works since the `\hfill` is *outside* the `\hbox` but it works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: That part I can explain.  Leaders are the general case of glue in TeX; usually, glue fills space with nothing.  But leaders fill space with whatever you want.  The general form of this is `\leaders{box or rule}\hskip{glue}`, Since `\hfill` is a special kind of infinitely strechable glue, the leaders command has the two things it need: an element to repeat and glue to tell it how far to extend the repetition.

Comment: With some code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17130/13450 this also works to surround text to both sides: `\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leavevmode\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill\kern0pt}`.

Answer (score 7):

The horizontal rule of 1pt height and raised by  1.5pt.

```
Hello \leaders\vrule height 2.5pt depth -1.5pt \hfill \null
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [ulem](https://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) which does this

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
normal text \uline{\textit{underline text}\hfill}
\end{document}
```

which will produce

[image: underline]

For your curiosity, the option `normalem` for package ulem prevents ulem to produce extra underline with `\em` or `\emph`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the command  \hrulefill
see  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Fill_the_rest_of_the_line

Comment: `\hrulefill` will indeed produce a rule filling the rest of the line. The question asked for a raised line, but I think a solution using `\hrulefill` would better a better starting point than using glue as suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

% I did it!
%

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\uline{Some text \hfill\phantom{.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).